# Kubernetes Java client API

Tags: api, kubernetes

I am trying to authenticate to the kubernetes cluster while using kubernetes java client API. I am using config file from `.kube/config` and pasting it into my project directory structure. But the config file has expiry time, and it expires so my API fails, also sometimes when i generate the `kubeconfig` file it does not contain expiry time, thus the API fails. How to get the permanent credentials for kubernetes cluster and use it in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Deploy the java application inside the kubernetes cluster as pod and use [InClusterClientExample](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/examples/InClusterClientExample.java). In this case since the pod uses [service account token](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/) it is guaranteed to work always because kubernetes takes care of refreshing the token.